# Would ripping DVDs greatly harm my DVD drive?

Tags: dvd, ripping

As opposed to playing or running stuff on the DVD? I'm planning to rip my DVDs so I can watch them on my device, but I'm afraid it'll kill the DVD drive real quickly. Is this a myth? Should I just go ahead and rip to my hearts content or should I be really careful?

Comment: It is a completely false myth perpetuated by the MPAA to discourage you from ripping DVDs.

Comment: I've seen more dvd drives go bad from complete lack of use then vise versa, if you're using a dvd drive these days period,  i'm amazed, that being said, use the hell out of it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard of that myth, in principle there shouldn't be any difference between playing a DVD and ripping it as far as the drive is concerned.

Comment: To add to the above answer (to ease your mind as well), there is no difference (to the DVD drive) if it is being played or being ripped as what happened to the DVD is that the data on the DVD is being read. The difference is then what is being done to the data you read from the DVD. Whether it is being played as video on your media player, or being decrypted and/or saved on your HDD for playback at later date made no difference on the DVD itself.